# Enable and Start Queue in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I need some help on how to configure Dockerfile so my queue works as expected. I already tried to run this manually inside container, so I need this to run Automatically after each deploy in gitlab. Here's what I did manually inside the container

- sudo service supervisor enable
- sudo service supervisor start
- ps aux | grep artisan

It works perfectly, but with Dockefile, I need it to run those commands. Heres my excerpt of the Dockefile

```
   COPY gal-worker /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gal-worker.conf
   COPY gal-schedule /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gal-schedule.conf
   RUN chown -R root:root /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
   # Make sure Supervisor comes up after a reboot.
   RUN sudo service supervisor enable 
   # Bring Supervisor up right now.
   RUN sudo service supervisor start
```

But my pipeline cant succeed due to errors:

```
   Step 33/34 : RUN sudo service supervisor enable
    ---> Running in c04c3ab807d2
   Usage: /etc/init.d/supervisord {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}
   The command '/bin/sh -c sudo service supervisor enable' returned a non-zero code: 1
   Cleaning up file based variables
   00:01
   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Commands like `service` mostly just don't work in Docker.  Don't try to run an init system here; just set the image's `CMD` to directly run the queue worker as a foreground process.

Comment: Have you tried to run in exec form? The example provided runs the command in shell form. Try exec one like this: `RUN ["sudo", "service", "supervisor", "enable"]`